# Internet Explorer 8 Font rendering to italics issue with Arial Black, Arial Bold Font

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

Kindly help, I am using  font-family: "Arial Black","Arial Bold",Gadget,sans-serif; in my project. All browsers are displaying it properly Except Internet Explorer 8, which is diaplying it in Italics.
Doctype i have used is :

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<![endif]-->
```

I tried to fix it by adding these, but did not succeed :

```css
font-family: "Arial Black","Arial Bold",Gadget,sans-serif;
font-style:normal;
```

OR

```css
@font-face {
 font-family: 'Arial Black';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
 font-family: 'Arial Bold';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Thanks for help

Comment: I don't know if it has to do with your problem, but I doubt that a doctype in conditional comments like that will do anything. Older IEs expected the doctype in the first line anyway, so they will use `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` in any case and which they quite fine.

Comment: Adjusting the Doctype in first line , did not work. Any other solution please.